# Google Chrome resolution nonoptimal for monitor

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, browser, resolution

I use Windows XP, and my monitor resolution is 1024x768 pixels, but in Chrome, the sites look too big.

I tried lowering the zoom of the browser with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>, but doesn't work well because the sites don't look as they should be. I thought that the problem was with Chrome, so I upgraded it to the latest version but even now it still shows sites zoomed in too far. Any ideas?

Comment: So IE is fine, but Chrome has the font too big? Just web pages or buttons and everythng too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the menu lines on the top right and set zoom to 100%.  Also you could go to menu -> settings -> advanced settings -> change the font and font size.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut to the original, 100% zoom is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, where <kbd>0</kbd> is the number zero (use numlock on the keypad).